# Upload large file via Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, file-upload, buffer

My company run an application that have to archive many kinds of files into some distants servers. The application works well but can't handle files larger than 1GB. 
Here is the current function use to load the files to be uploaded to the distant server :

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileToUploadPath);
byte[] fileArray = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(fileArray, 0, fs.Length);
```

The byte array (when loaded successfully) was then splited into 100Mb bytes arrays and sent to the local server (using some WSDL web services) with the following function :

```
localServerWebService.SendData(subFileArray, filename);
```

I changed the function responsible for the file reading to use BufferendStream and I also wanted to improve the Webservice part so that it doesn't have to create a new stream at each call. I thought of somethings like this :

```
FileInfo source = new FileInfo(fileName);
using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
    using (FileStream distantWriter = localServerWebService.CreateWriteFileStream(fileName))
    {
        using (BufferedStream buffReader = new BufferedStream(reader))
        {
            using (BufferedStream buffWriter = new BufferedStream(distantWriter))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                long bytesToRead = source.Length;

                while (bytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    int nbBytesRead = buffReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    buffWriter.Write(buffer, 0, nbBytesRead);

                    bytesRead += nbBytesRead;
                    bytesToRead -= nbBytesRead;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this code can't compile and always give me the error `Cannot convert MyNameSpace.FileStream into System.IO.FileStream` at line `using (FileStream distantWriter = localServerWebService.CreateWriteFileStream(fileName))`. I can't cast MyNameSpace.FileStream into System.IO.FileStream either.
The web service method :

```
[WebMethod]
public FileStream CreateWriteFileStream(String fileName)
{
    String RepVaultUP = 
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("SAS_Upload");
    String desFile = Path.Combine(RepVaultUP, fileName);

    return File.Open(desFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
}
```

So can you guys please explain to me why is this not working?

P.S.: English is not my mothertong so I hope what i wrote is clearly undestandable.

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend NOT to upload such large files "at once" and use/keep the splitting logic and send the files "part by part" and check the transmitted data after each block. Otherwise you will run int several other problems down the line at e.g 2GB or 4GB file size vs. ASP.NET and/or IIS limits...

Comment: can you implement an Async file upload process / methodology if so take a look at this link http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/

Comment: @ChrFin I also want to keep using a splitting logic. That's why i used buffered stream. I just wanted to avoid creating a new stream on each call to my webservice by using a webservice.CreateWriteFileStream() method.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Is it possible to do this using .NET 3.5 ? The async method seems dangerous because the documents are integrated in many workflows which shall not evolve before the files are completly downloaded.

Comment: here is a good article to read `Pierre-Antoine` 
[Asynchronous File I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx)